# Elegant way to count the number of lines that contain a string in a file

Tags: php, text-files, matching

I have a quick question.

As the title says, I'd like to find a way to count the number of lines that contain a specified string in a file, in PHP.

I know I could simply open the file and loop through all the lines and see if anything matches, but that seems kind of cumbersome. Is there a better way?

To further illustrate what I want to do, here's how it could look with awk:

```
awk '/KEYWORD/ {i++} END { print i }' FILE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hardly seems "cumbersome" to me:

```
$c = 0;
foreach(file($filename) as $line)
  if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) ++$c;
```

You might be able to get away with a regular expression, but if you truly want to count the lines (as opposed to instances), there's surely not a cleaner way (in terms of brevity and clarity) than the above method.

Edit, per the first comment:

```
echo substr_count(file_get_contents($filename), $str);
```

That should work.

Comment: I want the lines, but the format the file will be in makes it so that there is no difference if I count instances.

Comment: Then you could use `substr_count()` or even `count(preg_match_all())` on `file_get_contents()`. All of these methods will load the entire file into memory, which isn't advisable on large files.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer as the edit is even simpler than dvcolgan's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

be aware that file() will choke when run with stupid huge files such as 500MB+. If this is common in your web application, such as many concurrent users counting huge file sizes, this will impact on performance.